# Composer doesn't load classes

Tags: php, composer-php

This is my file structure:

```
-src/
--classes
---helloKitty.php
--public
---index.php
--vendor
--composer.json
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.6"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "src/classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
use Acme\helloKitty;

$hello = new helloKitty();
$hello->sayHello();
```

and helloKitty.php

```
namespace Acme;

class helloKitty
{
    public $hello = "Hello buddy";

    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo $this->hello;
    }
}
```

And simply sayin, it doesn't load my class. It's my first time with composer, but according to docs, everything is good, and i have no idea what's wrong.

This is mine error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Acme\helloKitty' not found in
>   C:\nginx\html\src\public\index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\nginx\html\src\public\index.php on line 6

Comment: Your use statement is before the autoload statement (in index.php)

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar Oh, changed it and still doesn't work. At first it was after autoload, but i already have no idea and was trying everything.

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I think that, if I am interpreting the folder structure correctly, the path to the classes is wrong. I think it should be `classes/`, as you are already in `src`.

Comment: @MikaTuupola yes, i run this everytime i change something in composer.json

Comment: @meun5 already tried that, doesn't help. Before src/ there is one more folder, in error you can see the path: C:\nginx\html\src\public\index.php so i guess src/ is correctly added. However just classes/ also doesn't work.

Comment: In the directory tree, the composer.json fille appears to be in the src directory. If that is correct the path to classes directory is invalid. You can also run composer dump-autoload -o and check the path in the autoload map inside the vendor directory